# Проверить наличие метода в классе

Tags: php, ооп

В статический класс передаются параметры: "name1, name2, etc..." Далее из этих имен формируется имя метода: "calcName1", "calcName2", .... Как лучше проверить, существует ли метод по его имени? Нашел следующие варианты: method_exists(), is_callable(), что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно непонятно чем вызван вопрос. Используйте [method_exists](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.method-exists.php)

```
<?php

class Test {

    public static function check($name, $name2) {
        var_dump(method_exists('Test', $name));
        var_dump(method_exists('Test', $name2));
    }

    public static function test1() {
        echo 111;
    }

    public static function test2() {
        echo 222;
    }
}


Test::check("test1", "test3");
```

выдаст

```
bool(true) bool(false)
```

Или

```
class Test {

    public static function test1() {
        echo 111;
    }

    public static function test2() {
        echo 222;
    }
}

var_dump(method_exists('Test','test1'));
var_dump(method_exists('Test','test3'));
```

также     `bool(true) bool(false)`